# DbSet<TableName> does not contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension method overload

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, polly

I'm using Polly to wrap all of my database commands in case of connection errors but I'm getting the above error when trying to write a custom method to run the Polly code. I'm using Entity Framework 6 and I thought I did everything right but obviously I missed something. This is pseudo code but hopefully you get the idea.

> DbSet< TableName > does not contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.Where< T >(IQueryable< T >, Expression<Func<T, bool>>)' requires a receiver of type IQueryable< T >

```cs
public static async Task<List<T>> HandleNetworkTask<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression, T table) where T : class
{
    try
    {
        using var context = new dbconfig();
        int maxRetries = 5;

        var retryPolicyAsync = Policy<T>.Handle<Exception>().WaitAndRetryAsync(maxRetries, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), (exception, timeSpan, retryCount, context) =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(6000);
        });
        var fallbackPolicyAsync = Policy<T>.Handle<Exception>().FallbackAsync(fallbackValue: null, onFallbackAsync: async (exc, con) => await ThrowExceptionInfo(exc.Exception));

        var retryPolicy = Policy<T>.Handle<Exception>().WaitAndRetry(maxRetries, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), (exception, timeSpan, retryCount, context) =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(6000);
        });
        var fallbackPolicy = Policy<T>.Handle<Exception>().Fallback(fallbackValue: null, onFallback: (exc, con) => ThrowExceptionInfo(exc.Exception).GetAwaiter().GetResult());

        switch (table)
        {
            case TableName:
                return await fallbackPolicyAsync.WrapAsync(retryPolicyAsync).ExecuteAsync(async () => 
                    {
                        return await context.TableName.Where<T>(expression).ToListAsync();
                    });
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ThrowExceptionInfo(ex);
    }
}
```

This is how I'm calling the method in my code:

```
var list = await HandleNetworkTask(x => x.Name == name && x.Date == date, new TableName(), true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to generics, I believe this type of code is illegal.

```
        switch (table)
        {
            case TableName:
                return await fallbackPolicyAsync.WrapAsync(retryPolicyAsync).ExecuteAsync(async () => 
                    {
                        return await context.TableName.Where<T>(expression).ToListAsync();
                    });
```

You can't run an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` against `DbSet<TableName>` even though you've effectively asserted T = TableName in this scenario.

What you can do is remove the whole table check (other than asserting it is a valid entity table) and executing:

```
return await context.Set<T>.Where(expression).ToListAsync();
```

I'd consider removing the "table" parameter and just call your method with the Type in the generic call:

```
var list = await HandleNetworkTask<TableName>(x => x.Name == name && x.Date == date, true);
```

From there you can inspect `<T>` within the method to assert that the only table passed in is a supported DbSet in your Context, throwing something meaningful if it's called for a table that isn't supported.